# Magento Duplicate content - sorting

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm wondering if someone could help.

We have a website and MOZ is reporting over 4K duplicate pages and more than 11K temporary redirects. mostly are the sorting options, How could this be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may enable canonical link meta tag for category listings by setting "Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories" configuration directive to "Yes".

You can find it in System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations.

This should result in adding code similar to this in page head on category pages:

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/category.html" />`

Then search engines should treat differently sorted versions of category listings as the same page.